# Implementing a stateless child component in React.js

Tags: javascript, user-interface, components, reactjs

I am trying to implement a stateless, React component, which will display directions (as text) in the footer -- I am calling it, the `Direction` component.  This component is intended to be included in other parent components, representing different pages, which pass in the necessary directions as props to be rendered by the `Direction` component.

```
// direction.js 
'use strict';

var React = require('react');

var Direction = React.createClass({

    propTypes: {
        directionText: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="direction">
                <p className="direction-text">
                    {this.props.directionText}
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }

});

module.exports = Direction;
```

```
// controller.js
var DirectionController = {
  // not sure how to configure it
};
```

I am not sure how I should configure the `controller`.

1. Do I even need the `controller`, since this component will simply be rendering text and doesn't handle user interactivity?
2. Is this component supposed to be as simple as I think it is?

I am new to React.

Comment: It's unclear to me what the purpose of `DirectionController` is. Can you elaborate?

Comment: That's my question no. 1 (above).  Most likely will not need the controller, since there is no user interactivity.

Comment: Whether or not you need it or not depends on what its purpose is. What exactly do you intend to use it for? What does it have to to with (the nonexistence of) interactivity? But maybe the very fact that I don't immediately can see the purpose means that you don't need it.

Comment: Even if you have no user interactivity, you will need to get the directions that you plan to pass to your Direction component from somewhere (otherwise you could have static HTML with unchanging directions). So what is the source of the direction?

Comment: Controller's aren't a common pattern with React, though components that contain and manage data are (and you could probably call those controllers). Take a look at https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005 for more details

Comment: @BinaryMuse While controllers in the way that Angular and Ember defines them aren't common, the concept of "view controllers" is quite common. A component that doesn't know a lot about rendering, but it knows a lot about data and state, and just passes that on to components that knows a lot about rendering, and less about data and state.

Answer (score 0):

You just include your Direction component in a render when you need it, passing in the property directionText with something that you want to display

```
render: function() {
    <div className="whatever-class">
      <Direction directionText="Some text to show" /> 
      <Direction directionText="Some some more more text text" /> 
    </div>
)
```